# PySimpleGui - Nesting Frames

Tags: python, user-interface, pysimplegui

[image]

How can I achieve nesting frames in this way.
One left Frame (Frame 1), one Right (Frame 2).
With another Frame (Frame 3) nested inside and but under the Left Frame contents?

Does the formatting allow for this?

Answer (score 6):

From outside to inside for your design

- Left Frame1, right Frame2 in main layout

```py
layout = [
    [sg.Frame("Frame1", ...), sg.Frame("Frame2", ...)],
]
```

- Top Frame 4, bottom Frame 3 in Frame1

```py
layout = [
    [sg.Frame("frame 4", ...],
    [sg.Frame("Frame 3", ...],
]
```

- Again, Left Frame 5, right Frame 6 in Frame 4

```py
layout = [
    [sg.Frame("Frame 5", ...), sg.Frame("Frame 6", ...)],
]
```

That's all !

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def blank_frame():
    return sg.Frame("", [[]], pad=(5, 3), expand_x=True, expand_y=True, background_color='#404040', border_width=0)

sg.theme('DarkGrey4')

layout_frame1 = [
    [blank_frame(), blank_frame()],
    [sg.Frame("Frame 3", [[blank_frame()]], pad=(5, 3), expand_x=True, expand_y=True, title_location=sg.TITLE_LOCATION_TOP)],
]

layout_frame2 = [[blank_frame()]]

layout = [
    [sg.Frame("Frame 1", layout_frame1, size=(280, 250)),
     sg.Frame("Frame 2", layout_frame2, size=(200, 250), title_location=sg.TITLE_LOCATION_TOP)],]

window = sg.Window("Title", layout, margins=(2, 2), finalize=True)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break

window.close()
```

[image]